# Mysql time format with auto %H:%i:%s

Tags: mysql, mysql5

This is my mysql query to select time from seconds.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(120),'%H:%i' )
```

This will return as 00:02 (HOUR AND MINUTES)

I need to show time hour,minutes,seconds automatically if there is a hour and there is a minute. no need to show like 00:00:10.

Is there any mysql function for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table `ss`:

```
id
50
70
3700
```

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5ab2/2)**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN id <60
      THEN TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(id),'%s' )
     WHEN id >= 60 AND id < 3600
      THEN TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(id),'%i:%s' )
     ELSE TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(id),'%H:%i:%s' ) END Time
 FROM ss
```

Result:

```
|     TIME |
------------
|       50 |
|    01:10 |
| 01:01:40 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT sec_to_time(now())
```

This function automatically gives you time in H:M:S

Comment: I tired with SELECT sec_to_time(360) but this also return 00:06:00 no need the 00 hour

Comment: See if this gives you only 06 then you will not know whether this is in hours , minute or in second.